# Delphi 10.1 berlin multiple ios SDKs

Tags: delphi

I have latest delphi and xcode etc running iphone sdk 10.2. Is there a way to setup a new platform and build to say ios 9? My list of sdks only shows 10.2. Not sure about supporting olders phones etc

Comment: See [Platform Status](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page). iOS 8,9,10 supported in Berlin.

Comment: Shows i can use ios8 but dont see anywhere on how i go about installing that version of sdk

Comment: [Adding an OS X or iOS SDK](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Adding_an_OS_X_or_iOS_SDK)

Comment: I only have 10.2 sdk available to select how do i get ios9?

Comment: Sorry but I can't help more than try to follow the doc's. For more accurate guidance, better ask Sarina at [Embarcadero help center](https://community.embarcadero.com/forum).

Comment: Lol all good i went down the same path thanks for your help. I think i need to install older versions of xcode will see how that goes

Comment: Like every other SDK, you get it from the software maker. For iOS and OSX, that would be Apple. For Android, that would be Google. For Windows, it would be MS. We're not the SDK URL finding service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to install earlier versions of SDK. The application compiled with Delphi Berlin will work at all versions of iOS, as stated in Options/Delphi Compiler/Linking/Minimum iOS version supported.
FMX library will work with iOS API 8..10 (there are some checks for version in source code - look for "TOSVersion.Check"). So as long as you will not use any extra iOS API "by hand", it will work for all devices running iOS 8..10. It is also possible, that basic applications will work for earlier versions, but it is of course unsupported.
For iOS 10 remember about extra security-related settings: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page
**Summary: you do not need separate SDK nor extra version of the app for different iOS versions.**

Remark about iOS development: in fact, xcode 8 also limits the target to iOS>=8, while you can setup it regardless of SDK in the project options in range 8..10. It is possible to force xcode 8 to compile and link against iOS 7 devices, but it is very hard to test and deploy, thus useless.

Comment: ok awesome, i will get an older device and test a basic app, thank you.